# Necessary and Sufficient Condition for a subset of an interval to be measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

While reading a book on Real Analysis, I came across the concept of Measurable Sets. One of the corollary of a theorem states that:-

*"A subset $A \subseteq \left[ a, b \right]$ is measurable if and only if $m^{*}\left( A \right) + m^{*}\left( A^{c} \right) \leq b - a$, where $A^{c}$ is the complement of set A relative to the interval $\left[ a, b \right]$"*

The photograph of the page is attached in the question.[image: This is the page where the corollary is proved.]

Now, my question is that is the statement true? Because I have two problems with the proof:-

1. The proof of the necessary part, i.e. "If $A \subseteq \left[ a, b \right]$ is measurable, then $m^{*}\left( A \right) + m^{*}\left( A^{c} \right) \leq \left( b - a \right)$", does not prove what it needs to prove. In fact, it proves: $m^{*}\left( A \right) + m^{*}\left( A^{c} \right) = \left( b - a \right)$.
2. In the sufficient part, they subtract (1) from (3). Here, (1) is an equation while (3) is an inequality. I do not think we can subtract an equation from an inequality.

Therefore, on thinking upon this a bit, I thought that there might be a printing error in the book and instead of the "less than or equal to ($\leq$)", there should be an "equal to (=)". Is my approach correct? Or is the textbook method correct?

This is the first time I have come across the Measure Theory and hence do not know much about it. A bit of deep explanations in the answers will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Because we always have $$m^{*}\left( A \right) + m^{*}\left( A^{c} \right) \geqslant \left( b - a \right),$$
the condition $m^{*}\left( A \right) + m^{*}\left( A^{c} \right) \leqslant \left( b - a \right)$ is equivalent to $m^{*}\left( A \right) + m^{*}\left( A^{c} \right) =\left( b - a \right)$.

(2) We can do that, this is "if $a\leqslant b$ and $c=d$, then $a-c\leqslant b-d$".

Everything is correct on your book.
But it would be better to make a remark that this also implies the equality.

Comment: So, yes, finally we would say that equality holds.